# Save AxAcroPDF file using iTextSharp in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, itext, axacropdf

Greetings to all iTextSharp geeks out there.

Q: Is it possible to save the pdf file that was viewed in AxAcroPDF viewer using iTextSharp, which retains the rotated position(specifically) of the document when edited in the AxAcroPDF or any edits in AxAcroPDF viewer?

Comment: Short answer is no. That control ( AxAcroPDF ) is for viewing only nothing more.

Comment: Also that library can do what you want but not with that viewer. You have to do it using the methods they provide and then save it and load it back into the viewer...

Comment: Damn! I'm stuck I guess. 
What my aim was, I have winform, a viewer with 3 buttons in place. 1 for counterclockwise rotation and 1 for the clockwise and the last one for saving the file. 

Is it possible to do this in iTextSharp?

much more depressing is I don't have basic knowledge about iTextSharp yet.

Comment: The issue is your going to have to determine what page did what. Then use iText to change the document and reload it.

Comment: The viewer you are using doesnt give you what you need to send back to iText to change.

Comment: Thank you for the reply bro. I guess i need another way to kill the cat. 
Actually I have an idea already. 

Just a quick question do you have an easy way how to save a pdf file using itextsharp?